# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Nopcommerce 2.40

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am trying to access the productservice in my OrderService like below but it throws error

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.

```
 //Many repositories are here just like 3 belows
 private readonly IRepository<Store> _storeRepository;  

 private readonly IRepository<ProductPicture> _productPictureRepository; 

 private readonly IRepository<Picture> _picture;  

 private readonly IProductService _productService; 

 //private readonly IProductService _productService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IProductService>();

   //tried above line but with no success
//Constructor for OrderService goes below
  public OrderService(IRepository<Store> storeRepository,
       IProductService productService
    )
    {
      _storeRepository = storeRepository;
        _productService= productService;
    }
```

If I remove reference for productService, application works well. I searched alot on web and on nopcommerce forum, but didnt find any solutions.

Any help?

Comment: Try putting a empty constructor like this ´public OrderService() { }´, let me know

Comment: Is this your OrderService or are you modifying the nop one?  It's possible that something in a dependency further up the chain from IProductService has a dependency on IOrderService, creating a circular reference that usually throws the error you are seeing.

Comment: Its orderservice from nop only and i have changed lot since in it

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the implementation for `IProductService` does not provided a parameterless contructor, or `public ProductServiceImpl() { }` and thus it cannot be resolved by the dependency injection framework.

When you register `IProductService` make sure you specify a constructor to use or create an empty one for the registered implementation.